# How to prove that this convex set is bounded?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

Let $M$ be an $n \times m$-matrix of real numbers. Let $\nu \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define the set $$S = \{  M^T \mu   \ \ | \ \ \mu \in \mathbb{R}^m \  \  \text{and} \  \ \mu \cdot  \nu \le 0 \ \ \} $$

How does one show that this set is bounded (having already showed it is closed and convex), if we are given that for any $\mu$ with $\mu \cdot v \le 0$, it holds that $M^T \mu$ cannot be positive (where by positive I mean nonnegative with at least one strictly positive element)?

In fact, the proof I want is the one where we assume that the set is unbounded, and then show that there exists a $\mu$ with the property that $\mu \in S$ and $M^T\mu > 0$ (one element strictly positive, all others nonnegative).

Comment: Your set is a cone and therefore unbounded. If $M^T\mu$ is in the set, then so is $M^T(2\mu)$. Are you just looking for a component-wise upper bound?

Comment: To say it a little clearer, if $\gamma \in S$, then so is $a\gamma$ for any $a > 0$. Thus $S$ is not bounded.